# Find all lines where the first word (and only the 1st word) contains a digit

Tags: regex, grep

Problem:
I have a text with multiple lines. One line can contain multiple sentences.
I need a regex that only shows the lines where the first word of the line itself contains a non-specific number (could be 1 or 2234234)

For example:

- `Thi5 is a t3st.` I want this line in my result.
- `This is also a test but with a number in the first word of the second sentence. Th1s is the 2nd sentence`, i don't want this in my result.
- `This is a t3st`, but i am also not interested in this line.
- `Th1s i want too.`
- `0r this one as well`
- `0r this one i want regardless of the whitepace in front of it`
- `But n0t this.`

I have to admit that i am a n00b at regex.
So far i found following:

```
^(.*)?[0-9](.*)?
```

However it will also match if there is a number in the e.g. third word but not the 1st one. 
I see that `^(.*)?` matches anything from the start of the line, so also any text up to the 3rd word which contains the number.

And to make it more complicated the 1st word could also contain special characters (`?/&%$"§` or any other).

If i would use a character class such as `^[a-zA-Z]?` instead of `^(.*)?` everything would be fine as far as i can see it, but it wouldn't catch whitespaces or special characters nor if there is more than one character in front of the number.

Comment: I have reformatted your post so you can see how to format verbatim ("preformatted") text.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the example. It seems there is no multiple line. And what is the `specific number` in the example?

Comment: Thanks Tim, i was wondering why it looked so messed up. Tried your example again and grep is not giving a result at all now (I had first a typo). guess it has to do with the options /gm passed in the regex tester.

Comment: I've just come back to my PC - you should always name the regex flavor you're using. Without that, you're likely to receive answers that don't exactly fit your requirements. For example, `grep` in its original mode doesn't know the `\d` shorthand that every modern flavor uses.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
^\s*\S*[0-9].*
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     # Start of string
\s*   # Match optional whitespace at the start of the line
\S*   # Match any number of characters except whitespace
[0-9] # Match a digit
.*    # Match the rest of the string
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qX0cK9).

Comment: Both examples only give the lines where NO words contain a number. if i replace .* in the first group with \w* it works but ignores leading whitespaces.

Comment: @user3425894: No. I've added a link to a regex tester so you can see for yourself.

Comment: ahhh ok, i am testing with grep and then it spits only the lines with no numbers out. Any idea on this one?

Comment: @user3425894 Which flavor of `grep` are you using?

Comment: @devnull: Presumably because I was using `\d` before the OP had stated that he was using `grep`.

Comment: Or maybe because somebody failed to understand it despite the explanation.

Comment: Yes Tim, it works as well, however not with the \d.* in grep. If i write it ^\s*\S*[0-9].* it does work fine. In this case the entire line is selected as a result. Thank you and dewd so much, i learned from you both more today than in the past week from books and a tutor. It clicked in many places now and the puzzle is coming together.

Comment: @user3425894 `\d` would work if your `grep` supports PCRE, i.e. if it provides the `-P` option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for whitespace. try: `^\s*\S*[0-9]+\S*\s`

`^` can either mean "anything except" e.g. `[^9]` is anything except the number 9, or it can mean match from the beginning of the string, as it does here.

`\s*` means match optional whitespace ie `\s` is match whitespace and `*` is zero or more times.

`\S*` is match optional non-whitespace. This is any character except newlines, carriage returns, space and tabs.

`[0-9]+` is match 1 or more numbers ie `[0-9]` is match numbers, and `+` is 1 or more times.

`\S*` - same as `\S*` above.

`\s` is match 1 whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks dewd, this is actually the closest result. It won't however show the line with a leading whitespace, but i can possibly live with this.

Comment: Added a \s*? at the front, now it works :). I am a happy bunny, now i want to understand it....so thank you so much, i am off reading now and taking this apart.

Comment: @user3425894 I've added an explanation of each of the components of the regex. I've also added optional whitespace to beginning of string.

Comment: Actually totally easy if one knows what one wants and what not and if it is not possible one way then maybe the other way around. I overlooked the \S* option that it will match any character apart from whitespaces and got a bit confused with the * that it means zero to many times and not at least one. And sure enough the first word is of course terminated by a whitespace at some stage of the line. Even if i terminate the first word by a dot it is caught due to the \S* at the end. I just don't know why i thought so complicated with groups in the beginning ;).

Comment: Now the next step is to just select the word itself with no leading or trailing whitespaces or any punctuation marks. I assume i need to look into Lookahead and Lookback.

Comment: @user3425894 wrap what you want to catch in parens. so ^\s*\S*[0-9]+\S*\s becomes ^\s*(\S*[0-9]+\S*)\s what's in the parens gets captured in a variable e.g $1. What language are you using?